# Getting an error while executing SSIS package

Tags: asp.net, database, ssis

In one of my project, I have to do some data transfer..So i created SSIS package for same but when i put it as schedule it throws me below error.

```
    An exception of type System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException occurred and was caught. 
Source:Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap;Message:Exception from HRESULT: 
0xC0047020;Target:Int32 AddRow(IntPtr);StackTrace:   at 
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSBuffer100.AddRow(IntPtr ppRowStart)     at 
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineBuffer.AddRow()     at 
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptBuffer.AddRow()     at 
OutAssetDetailBuffer.AddRow()     at ScriptMain.CreateNewOutputRows()  Method - 
CreateNewOutputRows()
```

Since i am new in SSIS package, i dont have any idea about this error. IF anybody knows what is the route cause behind this error than please let me know.

Also, I have one doubt - Does SSIS package requires Interop?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what is your package doing in the data flow?  what is the source?  add it stands,  your question cannot be answered without more detail

Comment: How you execute your package? Can you share the code?

Answer (score 3):

I've had that error, and it was actually not due to an error in the script component, but an error with a downstream task that caused the issue. Once that was resolved, the issue disappeared.

Hope this helps.